# How can I use a pattern rule to add prerequisites like I can to define variables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
all: foo/bar/baz

foo/%:
    @echo $(VAR)
    cp $@.in $@

# This works
foo/bar/%: VAR := Hello world

# This doesn't
foo/bar/%: foo/bar/%.in

foo/bar/baz.in:
    touch $@
```

When I run it, the output is

```
Hello world
cp foo/bar/baz.in foo/bar/baz
cp: cannot stat ‘foo/bar/baz.in’: No such file or directory
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'foo/bar/baz' failed
make: *** [foo/bar/baz] Error 1
```

In other words, the [pattern-specific variable rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific) works, but the equivalent syntax to declare an extra prerequisite doesn't.  What should I do instead?

The real use case is for copying headers before a build.  I wrote

```
obj/subdir/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -Igen/include
obj/subdir/%.o: | gen/include

gen/include:
        # Copy the headers
```

but the headers don't get copied.

Comment: Why does that `VAR` assignment take effect here? What target is being run that matches that pattern so that it should. I'm missing something here (unless it applies even though there is no actual target with that pattern that gets applied and some other pattern/target does the work).

Comment: Your "unless..." is right; https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific

Comment: Indeed. I'd not read that carefully enough in the past. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Pattern rules must define all prerequisite patterns when the rule is created; they cannot be added later.

Writing a pattern rule with no recipe [deletes the pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Comment: Okay, what should I do instead?

Comment: You have to either add the `| gen/include` to the original definition of the pattern rule where the recipe is defined, or else add it to all the targets explicitly (for example if you have a variable `OBJS` that contains all your object files you can write `$(OBJS) : | gen/include`.